# Kafka - delete topic is not working (ver - 2.x.x)

Tags: apache-kafka

Both of the below commands not deleting / flushing topic.

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --delete --topic myopic

bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --alter --topic mytopic --config retention.ms=1000
```

Comment: It worked after 10 minutes, i was expecting immediate.

Comment: Deleting topic is a totally async operation. What this command does is to mark the topic as "to-be-deleted" which is later seen by controller. So topic usually still exits even after the above command returns.